# selecting only values having difference greater than 0 (no negatives and 0)

Tags: sql, mysql, database

i've two columns in mysql db table **votes** : **accept** and **reject**

i want to query only the top result after the **accept-reject** column values

```
table : votes
=================
 accept | reject
=================
   7    |   9
   5    |   1
   2    |   15
   5    |   1
```

i want just the positive and top value, here **5**-**1** = **4**
actually, i've lot of other columns along with accept and reject..i just want to **ORDER** the results by the top value of **difference(positive only)** and **LIMIT** it to 1 so that i can get the one row i want..was i clear? :)
how to write query for this?
thanks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT t.accept,
          t.reject,
          t.accept - t.reject AS difference
    FROM VOTES t
   WHERE t.accept - t.reject > 0
ORDER BY difference DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Alternate using subquery:

```
SELECT v.accept,
       v.reject
  FROM VOTES v
 WHERE v.accept - v.reject > 0
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(t.accept - t.reject) AS difference
          FROM VOTES t
         WHERE t.accept - t.reject > 0) x ON x.difference = (v.accept - v.reject)
```

Comment: thanks but what i want is like:

 if all the values in the table are 0, it should not return any value..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (accept - reject) as top_value FROM table WHERE (accept - reject) > 0
```

So if you have values like this:

```
=============================
 accept | reject | top_value
=============================
   5    |   1    |   4
   7    |   9    |  -2
   2    |   15   |  -13
   5    |   5    |   0
```

the query will select only row 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming those two columns are just an extract from your table, and you want the entire row where (accept-reject) is maximum. Then you can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM votes
WHERE accept-reject = (SELECT MAX(accept-reject) FROM votes)
LIMIT 1
```